# how to convert json object to string format in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, json

This is my json format printed in output log
my 1st doubt is how i create separate class for **mystatus** object in json object
and with **mystatus** object i need to check whether the entered username and password is correct or not, if valid username means it should return value as "**s**"

This my response

```
{"login_response":[{"phone":"000000000","status":"Login Successfull",","**mystatus**":"S","mpin":"",","card_store_flag":"0"}]}
```

Comment: Qn isnt clear enough add more details please!!

Answer (score -1):

please try this.....

```
NSData *MyData = [jsonResponce dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSString *strString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:MyData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://yourwebservice link with json"];
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
if (myData == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"NO INTERNET");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"INTERNET EXIST");
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    for (id element in jsonArray)
    {
        NSString *durum = [element objectForKey:@"yourJsonHeader"];
        if([yourJsonHeader isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {


        }

    }

}
```